# What adapter to use with an AT connection for USB/PS2?

Tags: usb, keyboard, connection, ps2

I am planning on purchasing a vintage IBM model M keyboard.
From the specs I can see that the connection that it uses is an "AT" connection.

What sort of adapter would I need to get to make it work with a PS2 or USB connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need one of [these](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10414&cs_id=1041401&p_id=1126&seq=1&format=2), then a PS/2-to-USB adapter.

I'm not aware of an AT-to-USB adapter.

Comment: the ps2 to usb would have to be a signal converter type, not a passive adaptor type. otherwise it certanily won't work. 'cos even old ps2 keyboards with a passive ps2 to usb adaptor wouldn't work in usb otherwise.  see http://superuser.com/questions/108763/how-can-i-insert-my-ps2-mouse-in-usb-port